# SvelteKit with FastAPI in DockerCompose

Tags: javascript, python, fastapi, fetch-api, sveltekit

I have an issue understanding how to make an API call to my FastAPI Docker container from SvelteKit Docker container running in Docker-compose and preserve Cookies set by FastAPI.

I need to post a formData with EMAIL and PASSWORD fields from SvelteKit to FastAPI. I'm trying to use Actions in SvelteKit to make the call from the page.server.js

```
export const actions = {
  login: async (event) => {
    const formValues = await event.request.formData();
    const email = formValues.get("email");
    const password = formValues.get("password");

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("email", email);
    formData.append("password", "1");

    const res = await event.fetch(
      "http://fastapi_backend:8000/web_api/users/sessions",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
        credentials: "include", // include cookies in the request
      }
    );
```

I can extract the cookie from the response and set it to the browser no problem:

```
const jwt = res.headers.get("set-cookie").split('"')[1];
event.cookies.set("jwt", jwt);
```

However, when I make another request again I expect the Cookies to be sent with the *event.fetch* but my FastAPI container does not see any. This is expected as it's stated in SvelteKit Docs:

`Cookies will only be passed through if the target host is the same as the SvelteKit application or a more specific subdomain of it.`
[SvelteKit Docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/types#public-types-requestevent)

I can not imagine how to do this now. I'm testing this workflow outside of Docker-compose now.

All I know is that if I make this API call from the *page.svelte* in browser I wouldn't have access to *http://fastapi_backend:8000* which is the Docker-compose name of the FastAPI container.

How should I do this? Is the only real way to do this is to expose the FastAPI container to the outside and make the call from the browser from *page.svelte*?

Please help!

I've tested FastAPI with Postman and it successfully sends and receives cookies.
I've also tried making the call from the browser from *page.svelte* and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer on [SvelteKit's Gihub Page](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/5195):

> If you want to call your backend services and spoof like you're a browser, you can do so! Copy all your headers over. If you want to forward a backend service's "set-cookie" directive to the browser, go ahead. But if you do nothing the calls to the backends get no headers, just as if you made a curl call, which seems like a pretty reasonable thing to do by default.

```
export default async function load({ event, params, fetch }) {
  let response = await fetch('https://a.backend.com/data/' + event.id, {
    headers: {
      // Use end user credentials
      // You could parse the cookie string and slice out a specific auth cookie, or
      // or just pass the whole darn thing.
      cookie: event?.request.headers.get('cookie'), // only relevant server-side
      credentials: 'include', // only relevant client-side
    },
  });
  ...
}
```

In my case it results to this function:

```
export const actions = {
  login: async (event) => {
    let jwt = event.cookies.get("jwt");
    console.log("JWT COOKIE IS: ", jwt);

    const formValues = await event.request.formData();
    const email = formValues.get("email");
    const password = formValues.get("password");
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("email", email);
    formData.append("password", "12345");

    const res = await event.fetch(
      "http://127.0.0.1:8000/web_api/users/sessions",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
        headers: {
          cookie: `jwt=${jwt}`,
          credentials: "include", // include cookies in the request
        },
      }
    );

    // reset the cookie
    jwt = res.headers.get("set-cookie").split('"')[1];
    event.cookies.set("jwt", jwt);
```